# OpenSearch compute knn index size properly

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, opensearch

I am using OpenSearch service in AWS for my research.

Task: I want to compute the index size for N records in the index.

Input: I have only one node in AWS [r6g.4xlarge.search] with 128 RAM. The index definition is:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "knn":                           True,
            "knn.space_type":                "cosinesimil",
            'number_of_replicas':            0,
            'refresh_interval':              -1,
            'translog.flush_threshold_size': '10gb',
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "vector": {
                "type":      "knn_vector",
                "dimension": 512
            },
            "keyword1":   {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "keyword2":    {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I see that after force merge + refresh I have 5 segments.

The KNN stats looks like:

```
{"_nodes":                    {"total": 1, "successful": 1, "failed": 0}, "cluster_name": "NAME",
     "circuit_breaker_triggered": false, "nodes": {
        "ID": {"miss_count":             7, "graph_memory_usage_percentage": 34.527355,
                                   "graph_query_requests":   475, "graph_memory_usage": 16981999,
                                   "cache_capacity_reached": false, "graph_index_requests": 5,
                                   "load_exception_count":   0, "load_success_count": 7, "eviction_count": 0,
                                   "indices_in_cache":       {
                                       "INDEX_NAME": {"graph_memory_usage_percentage": 34.527355,
                                                        "graph_memory_usage":            16981999,
                                                        "graph_count":                   5}},
                                   "script_query_errors":    0, "script_compilations": 0,
                                   "script_query_requests":  0, "graph_query_errors": 0, "hit_count": 468,
                                   "graph_index_errors":     0, "knn_query_requests": 95,
                                   "total_load_time":        57689947272, "script_compilation_errors": 0}}}
```

I found that the required amount of memory in my case is [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/knn/knn-index/#hnsw-memory-estimation): 1.1 * (4 * dimension + 8 * M) bytes. Where dimension=512, M=16 which gives me 0.0000023936 per record. Now I have 7885767 documents in the index and it takes 16981999 = ±16GB - 32% in use from avail memory. So it is even less than the formula says.

But if I compute the available memory it gives me ~50GB for instance with 128 GB RAM. According to AWS docs [(check the bottom line)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/knn.html) the OpenSearch itself takes up to 32 GB so 96 left. **Can you explain to me how to write a formula to estimate the amount of documents in the index properly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. If you are using only knn search (like me) you can simply increase this parameter to itlize the maximum RAM of your machine `knn.memory.circuit_breaker.limit` [settings](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/knn/settings/)

You can change it from python (or elasticsearch api)

```
import elasticsearch

es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(
    hosts=["host"],
    http_auth=(
        "admin",
        "admin",
    ),
    timeout=3600,
)
res = es.cluster.put_settings(
    {"persistent": {"knn.memory.circuit_breaker.limit": "100%"}}
)
print(res)
```

Comment: but can this be changed on the AWS managed service? I think not.

Comment: I was able to do it. This allowed me to increase the capacity of a node and I didn't notice any performance issues. Just to be clear I have used a single node opensearch instance. Anyway I think that the price for my scenario was to big so I migrated to self-hosted solution :)

Comment: Gotcha. Could you show what command you used to do it? I got denied on changing cluster settings, which I sort of expected in this case.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a code sample. Sorry I don't know what permissions are required in case AWS. I've used a `master user`.